# Adding asp table inside Templatefield

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, templatefield

Here i have a problem with adding asp table inside the template field in gridview.
 in my gridview one button is there named as "View" when i click this it should display all information below that row... so how do i do that??? should i use template  field?? how to add button("View") for each row using this template field
Please correct my code

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Table ID="tblModify" runat="server" Width="100%" Visible="False" CssClass="table">
                                <asp:TableRow>
                                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell35" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right"><h1>Debit Information</h1></asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow6" runat="server">
                                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">DebitNoteNumber</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell
                                        ID="TableCell4" runat="server">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDebitNoteId" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Columns="70" />
                                    </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell ID="TableCell5" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">Date</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell
                                        ID="TableCell6" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" MaxLength="30" Columns="50"></asp:Label>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server">
                                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell11" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">Patient Name</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell
                                        ID="TableCell37" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPatientName" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Columns="70"></asp:Label>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell1" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">Patient Number</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell
                                        ID="TableCell2" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPatientId" runat="server" MaxLength="50" Columns="70"></asp:Label>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow2" runat="server">
                                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell38" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">Phone Number</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell
                                        ID="TableCell39" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblPatientPhoneNumber" runat="server">  </asp:Label>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell7" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">Bill Number</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell
                                        ID="TableCell8" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblBillId" runat="server">  </asp:Label>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow5" runat="server">
                                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell9" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">Receipt Number</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell
                                        ID="TableCell10" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblReceiptId" runat="server" MaxLength="30" Columns="50"></asp:Label>

                                    </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell ID="TableCell13" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">Amount</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell
                                        ID="TableCell14" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAmount" runat="server" MaxLength="30" Columns="50"></asp:Label>
                                    </asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                                <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow8" runat="server">
                                    <asp:TableCell ID="TableCell15" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Right">Balacne</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell
                                        ID="TableCell16" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblBalacne" runat="server" MaxLength="30" Columns="50"></asp:Label></td>
                                    </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell></asp:TableCell>
                                </asp:TableRow>
                            </asp:Table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

if i use this code, i could't find button("View") in my gridview...

Answer (score 0):

U can use  Modal Pop Up Extender.
write simple html table tag(TR,TD) with your server side tag into the modal pop up.When You click on "View" the details will be shown into Modal pop up.